# Style Page Buttons Differently than Select Buttons

Tags: .net, css, gridview, css-selectors

I'm trying to style my paging buttons differently than my select buttons. The selector I'm using for the select buttons applies to paging buttons as well:

```
.gridView tr td a{} /* I've assigned the gridView class to the GridView */
```

How can I select only the paging buttons? I tried this:

```
.gridView tr td table tr td a{} //traced this down using Chrome's Inspect Element
```

EDIT: here's the HTML (writing this in ASP.NET)

```
<div class="gridViewContainer">
    <div>
<table class="gridView" cellspacing="0" rules="rows" border="1" id="GridViewName" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th><th scope="col">FRAME</th><th scope="col">ELEV</th><th scope="col">CW</th><th scope="col">LEVEL</th>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridViewName&#39;,&#39;Select$0&#39;)">Select</a></td><td>MT</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridViewName&#39;,&#39;Select$1&#39;)">Select</a></td><td>QA</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridViewName&#39;,&#39;Select$2&#39;)">Select</a></td><td>QA</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridViewName&#39;,&#39;Select$3&#39;)">Select</a></td><td>VX</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridViewName&#39;,&#39;Select$4&#39;)">Select</a></td><td>PP</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridViewName&#39;,&#39;Select$5&#39;)">Select</a></td><td>PP</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td colspan="6"><table>
            <tr>
                <td><span>1</span></td><td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridViewName&#39;,&#39;Page$2&#39;)">2</a></td><td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridViewName&#39;,&#39;Page$3&#39;)">3</a></td><td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridViewName&#39;,&#39;Page$4&#39;)">4</a></td><td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridViewName&#39;,&#39;Page$5&#39;)">5</a></td><td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridViewName&#39;,&#39;Page$6&#39;)">6</a></td><td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridViewName&#39;,&#39;Page$7&#39;)">7</a></td><td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridViewName&#39;,&#39;Page$8&#39;)">8</a></td><td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridViewName&#39;,&#39;Page$9&#39;)">9</a></td><td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridViewName&#39;,&#39;Page$10&#39;)">10</a></td><td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridViewName&#39;,&#39;Page$11&#39;)">...</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: see my edit, added html

Comment: Your second selector seems to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/TCSrf/

Comment: have you tried using `<PagerSettings>` and `<PagerStyle>` within ASP.NET?

Comment: In using PagerStyle, setting the BackColor changes the background colour of the cell itself, not the page buttons/links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this article](http://atashbahar.com/post/GridView-makeover-using-CSS.aspx) , a detailed demo on how to style the GridView.

Most notably the `PagerStyle-CssClass` attribute.